# Easy way(builtin function) to put Main title in plot in octave

Tags: plot, octave, subplot, built-in

I'm using **octave** for plotting subplots in same plot and want to add general title isn't there any builtin function like `sgtitle` in **matlab** as in that  [this old question](https://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Main-title-in-plot-td1630563.html)
there was a solution but not using any cool builtin functions and octave dosen't .also here  [Octave - Bugs: bug #55019, new sgtitle function](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?55019)  I find there is `sgtitle` in octave but can't find doc or package name or any thing ...is it not fully implemnted yet  or some alternative ???

**I'm asking about package or bultin function not implementation I'll write or copy from someone**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on your definition of "builtin function" vs 'workaround'.

A full-window title is simply a title positioned with respect to an empty 'whole window' axis, as opposed to subtitles which are positioned with respect to subplots which take up only a fraction of the window at specific positions.

Therefore the 'builtin' way to add a title on an empty whole-window axis, is to simply add a title on an empty whole-window axis.

```
t = 0:0.01:2*pi;
hold on
s1 = subplot( 2, 2, 1 ); plot( t, sin(t) ); set( s1, 'title', 'Sine of t' );
s2 = subplot( 2, 2, 2 ); plot( t, cos(t) ); set( s2, 'title', 'Cosine of t' );
s3 = subplot( 2, 2, 3 ); plot( t, tan(t) ); set( s3, 'title', 'Tangent of t' );
s4 = subplot( 2, 2, 4 ); plot( t, cot(t) ); set( s4, 'title', 'Cotangent of t' );
S  = axes( 'visible', 'off', 'title', 'Trigonometric Functions' );
hold off
```

[image]

In my opinion, this is as 'builtin' as it gets (in that, I don't think of setting a title on a main axes object to be any less of a builtin functionality than setting a title on the individual subplot axes objects).

If by 'builtin' you meant "I'd like to use a single-word command to do this instead of relying on built-in graph properties", then no, octave does not provide such a convenience function.

Comment: Well, I have to apologise. I thought it would be obvious to someone familiar with the graphing syntax that this would be the canonical way to add a main title to a figure, but reading the bug report you linked to shows that this was not as obvious to the octave developer in that thread. I hesitate to call using the graph properties in their intended manner a 'workaround', but if it was not immediately obvious to an octave _developer_ then maybe this only qualifies as 'quasi-builtin' :p I have linked your question in the bug report you linked to. Thanks for your asking this question!